# populate_sdk error for meta-toolchain-qt5

Tags: qt5, yocto, build-system

I am compiling qt sdk for boudary devices morty version of yocto below error if comming I can not able to find the error

```
ERROR: meta-toolchain-qt5-1.0-r0 do_populate_sdk: Unable to install packages. Command '/home/siva/yocto//boundary-eval-
image/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/smart --log-level=warning --data-dir=/home/siva/yocto//boundary-eval-image/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/sdk/image/var/lib/smart install -y packagegroup-cross-canadian-nitrogen6x@x86_64_nativesdk nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host@x86_64_nativesdk nativesdk-packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-host@x86_64_nativesdk' returned 1:
Loading cache...
Updating cache...               ######################################## [100%]

Computing transaction...error: Can't install nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host-1.0-r12@x86_64_nativesdk: no package provides nativesdk-shadow


ERROR: meta-toolchain-qt5-1.0-r0 do_populate_sdk: Function failed: do_populate_sdk
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/siva/yocto/boundary-eval-image/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sdk.71127
ERROR: Task (/home/siva/yocto/sources/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/meta/meta-toolchain-qt5.bb:do_populate_sdk) failed with exit code '1'
```

any solutions??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error: `Computing transaction...error: Can't install nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host-1.0-r12@x86_64_nativesdk: no package provides nativesdk-shadow`

That's come from missing the `shadow` package: http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-extended/shadow/shadow_4.2.1.bb?h=morty

Make sure that you have it then recompile again.